# RHEL 6, PHP 5.3.3, symfony 1.4.[12] -> irregular PHP Fatal error: Class 'sfProjectConfiguration' not found in

Tags: php, symfony-1.4, rhel6

i deploy a symfony 1.4 project on a RHEL 6 Server with PHP 5.3.3. 
On a irregular basis I get entries in the php error log complaining that sfProjectConfiguration could not be found and the request fails. The same request then runs smoothly the next time.
There is no memcache or apc installed.
On other machines it works flawless.

Any ideas how to solve or investigate the problem?

Comment: Hm after a restart of the server it looks better.
"Have you tried to turn it off an on again" - The IT crowd.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes i have an fimiliar error in frontend/backend_dev. Does the error occur when you use on of them? It happens to me when I "hammer" the F5-Button. Could be a cache-rebuilding problem.

Comment: We traced it down to the PHP Version. With 5.3.3 it happended with 5.3.4 and above not anymore. But this was very annoying and painful to find out.

Comment: You should write this as an aswer and accept it as it may help other users in future.